# Xamarin Forms PCL save instance state

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, onsaveinstancestate

I developed a Xamarin Forms application with a Portable Class Library. The orientation of my app is landscape. So whenever my screen goes black and I return to my app, the screen is 'reseted'. In my application, buttons change color by pressing them.
Is there a possibility to save the state of the buttons, such as with the OnSaveInstanceState in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/#Preventing_Activity_Restart) guide. It is pretty simple, just add

```
[Activity (Label = "ActivityName", ConfigurationChanges=Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
```

above your activity :)

Comment: The property ConfigurationChanges indeed solved my problem. Thx @DDerTyp